# is it possible to insert data where null value is locating by using insert into keyword

Tags: sql

```
Insert into table_name  
values('hyd') where col1 isnull;
```

Comment: That should be possible. I think you need to look at the syntax for an UPDATE statement relevant to the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: for existing data  if we want to replace then we should go with Update

Comment: may be this is correct   update table_name set col1='hyd' where col1='null'

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT` syntax can't have `WHERE` clause. You can use `INSERT INTO` command for this type of use case.

Comment: Perhaps [adding an example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46387155/edit) based on the question would help the OP understand your answer better.